# Form with nested fields_for which saves to multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, parameters, fields-for

I have three models,  `companies`, `transactions` and `subtransactions`. Each *has_many* of the next. I need to build a form that saves to both `transactions` and multiple records of `subtransactions`.

I'm struggling with the best approach to the form and the appropriate way to save to the DB. Ideally, the records get saved at once if all pass validation.

My simplified form:

```
<%= form_for(@transaction) do |f| %>
  <div class="field" id="transaction_amount">
    <%= f.label :total %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :total %>
  </div>

    <% 1.upto(5) do |i| %>
          <%= fields_for("subtransaction[#{i}]") do |s| %>
              <div class="field" id="subtotal_amount">
                <%= s.label :subtotal, "Subtotal #{i}" %><br>
                <%= s.text_field :subtotal %>
              </div>
          <% end %>
    <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

My TransactionsController:

```
def new
    @transaction = company.transactions.build if logged_in?
end

def create
    @transaction = company.transactions.build(transaction_params)

    params[:subtransaction].each do |i|
        # build and save
    end

    if @transaction.save ## @subtransaction.save
        flash[:success] = "Success!"
        redirect_to success_url
      else
         render :new
      end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this is to pass the `nested` attributes through the various models:

```
#app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :transactions
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :transactions
end

#app/models/transaction.rb
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sub_transactions
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_transactions
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @transaction = company.transactions.new
      5.times do
        @transaction.sub_transactions.build
      end
   end

   def create
      @transaction = company.transactions.new transaction_params
      @transaction.save
   end

   private

   def transaction_params
      params.require(:transaction).permit(sub_transactions_attributes: [:subtotal])
   end
end
```

Then...

```
#app/views/transactions/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @transaction do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :sub_transactions do |s| %>
      <%= s.text_field :subtotal %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to save the various nested attributes through the main object. It is the correct, [conventional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very useful. Just a final note, does this mean I should perform validations for the subtransaction attributes in the Transaction model as well?

Comment: No - you should keep the validations in their respective models. However, you may also need [`inverse_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) to make the data accessible in each associated model.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it submits only one sub_transactions, instead of an array of them, which is what rails seems to expect, so it ends up raising an error

Answer (score 2):

#### model

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subtransations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subtransactions
end
```

#### controller

```
def new
  @transaction = Transaction.new
  @transaction.subtransactions.build
end

def create
  company = Company.first # Or whatever you need.

  # We merge the company id to the transaction params since 
  # a transaction belongs_to a company.
  @transaction = Transaction.create!(create_params.merge(company_id: company.id))
end

private

def create_params
  params.require(:transaction).permit(
    :total,
    subtransactions_attributes: [:id, :subtotal]
  )
end
```

#### view

```
<%= form_for(@transaction) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :total %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :total %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :subtransaction do |s| %>
    <div class="field" id="subtotal_amount">
      <%= s.label :subtotal %><br>
      <%= s.text_field :subtotal %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

*This will allow to create only one subtransaction with the transaction record*

If you want to create more than one `subtransaction` record you should use [cocoon **gem**](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), it's easy to setup and will save much precious time.

Comment: I had to downvote for the inefficiency in `create_params`

Comment: Thanks Marwen for your answer. Very useful. I will check out the gems you suggested as well. Cheerio!

Comment: @RichardPeck how is create_params inefficient? Maybe elaborate a little bit? that would be helpful.